# IBOutlet equals nil

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

I just tried connecting my UIWebView with UIViewController and when I started application I got error that mean UIWebView equals nil. What problem can be?

[image: Error in this image]

Comment: You should stop using UIWebView - it is leaking like there is no tomorrow. Use WKWebView or SFSafariViewController.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll see this sort of behavior if you just referenced `AuthViewController()`, but didn't reference the storyboard at all. That's because when you simply create an instance of a `AuthViewController`, it has no way of knowing what scene in the storyboard that class is associated with. Thus, all of the `IBOutlet` references will be `nil`.

Instead, if you're programmatically transitioning to this scene, you can instantiate the view controller using its "storyboard ID":

1. Specify the storyboard ID for the view controller's scene in the "Identity Inspector" in the right panel in Interface Builder:

   [image]
2. Once you do that, rather than doing something like the following, which will not work:

   ```
   let controller = AuthViewController()
   // now do something with `controller`, e.g.
   presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
   ```

   You can now properly instantiate this `AuthViewController` using its storyboard ID:

   ```
   let controller = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("AuthScene")
   presentViewController(controller!, animated: true, completion: nil)
   ```

Alternatively, if you want to transition between two scenes, I prefer to use the storyboard segues:

1. So create a segue between the two scenes by <kbd>control</kbd>-dragging from the view controller icon above the original scene to the destination scene:

   [image]

   That creates a segue which isn't linked to any buttons or anything like that. It's just a segue directly between the two scenes that won't be invoked until you do so programmatically.
2. Give that segue its own storyboard ID:

   [image]
3. Now you can perform that segue programmatically:

   ```
   performSegueWithIdentifier("TransitionToAuthScene", sender: self)
   ```

The advantage of this latter approach is that (a) the storyboard now visually represents the flow of your application; and (b) you can use unwind segues or the like.

--

A couple of final thoughts:

- If you didn't programmatically transition to this scene, the other possibility is that you didn't hook up the `IBOutlet` in Interface Builder. Given that the "Auth Web View" label is showing up in the document outline, I presume you did hook up the `IBOutlet` successfully, but it is the other thing to check. You can confirm this by selecting the web view and then looking at the "Connections Inspector" panel on the right in Interface Builder:

  [image]
- Later in comments you made reference to performing this transition in `viewDidLoad`. This is invariably the wrong place to be transitioning to a new scene from your storyboard, because you're frequently going to be in the middle of transitioning to the scene in question, and iOS is going to get confused.

  It's better to defer this sort of code until `viewDidAppear` (or skipping the "source" view controller and transitioning directly to this "auth" scene).

Comment: @cmashinhk - Then, it's likely to be my first point, how you instantiated the view controller. Did you use the `AuthViewController()` syntax?

Comment: by viewDidLoad. Can you write me to e-mail? cmashinho@gmail.com

Comment: It's probably better and more useful to future readers if we can resolve the issue here. I'd suggest you update your question with code snippet and/or description of how you're transitioning to `AuthViewController`, and if you're doing this programmatically, with a focus on how you're instantiating this `AuthViewController`.

Comment: @cmashinho - Then supplying the scene in InterfaceBuilder a storyboard id and then using `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` rather than `AuthViewController()` will fix that. See expanded answer. Also see my caveat about doing this in `viewDidLoad`.