# Xcode 7 Swift - showsUserLocation = true not working

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, swift

I have been trying to make my own mapView that displays your current location so I went to watch *Vea Software's* video link [found here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qrdIL44T6FQ) and I did these steps

1. Wrote the code:

   ```
   //
   //  ViewController.swift
   //  MapView
   //
   //  Created by HTML SUES ADMIN on 10/5/15.
   //  Copyright © 2015 HTML SEUS. All rights reserved.
   //

   import UIKit
   import MapKit
   import CoreLocation

   class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate
   {
   @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

   let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

   override func viewDidLoad()
   {
   super.viewDidLoad()

   self.locationManager.delegate = self
   self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
   self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
   self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
   self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
   self.mapView.showsUserLocation = true


   override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
   super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
   // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
   }

   // MARK: - Location Delegate Methods
   func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

   let location = locations.last

   let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location!.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location!.coordinate.longitude)

   let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 1, longitudeDelta: 1))

   self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)

   self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()

   }

       func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: NSError) {
   print("Errors: " + error.localizedDescription)
           }

   }
   ```
2. Realized I made a mistake and added this piece of code under

   ```
   super.viewDidLoad()
   ```

   I added,

   ```
   self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
   self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
   ```
3. Added this under [Info.plist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7CdJl.jpg) (it's a imgur file/no download)
4. Ran the Xcode project got the map to pull up with the Location notification but didn't show current location. Instead came up with this

> Errors: The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCLErrorDomain error 0.)
>
> Errors: The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCLErrorDomain error 0.)

yes 2 of the same, I think because of

```
    self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
```

but maybe it's because the location is not in iPhone Simulator so it bugs out.

So 2 things to help me with:

1. how to find your current location if there is any way?
2. why does it only work on the first **View Controller** and not the second one? It is embedded in a navigation controller.

Comment: Is linked mapView with the storyboard?

Comment: Ie, is there an empty circle next to the declaration of the `mapView` variable in the left margin next to the `@IBOutlet` (indicating that the outlet is not hooked up), or is there a solid dot inside the "connect" circle (suggesting it is hooked up)?

Comment: @Rob theres a solid circle inside the circle next to `@IBOutlet`

Comment: @JavierFloresFont yes

Comment: @htmlsues - OK, then the question is why `mapView` is `nil`. One question is how `ViewController` was instantiated. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/32812352/1271826.

Comment: @Rob - It does not work, maybe this will clear something up. I'm using a navigation controller and was following Vea Software's video on how to do it but I'm not using it on my main `ViewController` I was using this video to help me [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qrdIL44T6FQ) (link to video)

Comment: If you're not doing this on the main view controller, like that video describes, show us how you instantiated the view controller on which the map view resides. Whenever you have a `nil` for `IBOutlet` that has a solid dot next to it, the problem is invariably how the view controller was instantiated. Please edit your question to show us how you instantiated and/or how you transitioned to this view controller with the map view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok to start off I know this is weird to answer my own question but after further research I have came up with this answer

> Errors: The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCLErrorDomain error 0.) = This error occurs if you have Scheme/Edit Scheme/Options/Allow Location Simulation checked but **don't have a default location set.**

**don't have a default location set.** - was my problem thanks everyone who helped